# problem about [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

Tags: iphone

I got a problem when disable/enable the iphone idle function.

I try to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];` to disable the iphone idle function, and it works fine.

Then i try to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];` to enable the idle function in a button click event. But it turned out to be not working.

I use my ipod touch device(OS4.1) to test this function. Any idea?

Comment: Is your code actually called (and when)? Is it run on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, it's running on the main thread. I put a NSLog right after the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO]. I can see the log in the console. But after few minutes the device is still on and not go to idle.

Comment: Does the screen turn off if you don't disable the idle timer? Maybe try running without the debugger connected?

Comment: If i didn't disable the idle timer in the first time, the screen will turn off in a minute. But after i disabled it, then i enable it. it won't work as expected.